# Why does the assignment operator assign to the left-hand side?

Tags: language-design, history

I began teaching a friend programming just recently (we're using Python), and when we began discussing variable creation and the assignment operator, she asked why the value on the right is assigned to the name on the left, and not vice-versa.

I had not thought about it too much before, because it seemed natural to me, but she said that left-to-right seemed more natural to her, since that's how most of us read natural languages.

I thought about it, and concluded that it makes code much easier to read, since the names that are assigned to (which the programmer will need to reuse) are easily visible, aligned on the left.

```
aligned = 2
on = 'foo' + 'bar' + 'foobar'
the = 5.0 / 2
left = 2 + 5
```

As opposed to:

```
2 = aligned 
'foo' + 'bar' + 'foobar' = on
5.0 / 2 = the 
2 + 5 = right 

# What were the names again...?
```

Now I wonder if there are other reasons as well for this standard. Is there a history behind it? Or is there some technical reason why this is a good option (I don't know much about compilers)? And are there any programming languages that assign to the right side?

Comment: [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) can assign to the right-hand side (`value -> variable`).

Comment: Perhaps this is due to bad variable names?
How about 'numAligned is 2` and 'chickensLeft is 2+5'?

Comment: Is your friend's name... Yoda?

Comment: and there are languages with polish notation and others with rpn

Comment: Reminds me of `if (3 == i)` to avoid the =/== typo

Comment: @Job: Well, I obviously wouldn't use names like that when teaching someone (or when programming at all, really), but for the sake of the question I thought they'd be appropriate. :]

Comment: If she starts compaining about this, I wonder what will she do when she sees C++ & co.

Comment: With instructions that have two arguments, some assembler notations put the destination first (e.g. 8086) and others but the destination last (e.g. 68000). Some old high level languages include something along the lines of `move x to y` - COBOL and xBase are both probables (I don't remember for sure). C++ stream-extraction has a certain assign-to-the-right-ishness - with only one `>>` in an expression, at least.

Comment: Because when we learn algebra, we solve for x in this fashion, ending up with x = <result>.

Comment: Just a side note: Khan Academy has some lessons on Python for beginner programmers: http://www.khanacademy.org/#computer-science and Google has some for more advanced: http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/set-up.html

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Ditto @paxdiablo. The early programming languages were written by mathematicians--actually all of them were. In mathematics, by her own principle--reading left to right-- it makes sense in the way it works.

x = 2y - 4.

In mathematics, you would say this: Let x be equal to 2y -4.

Also, even in algebra you do this. When you solve an equation for a variable, you isolate the variable you are solving for to the left side. i.e. y = mx + b;

Furthermore, once an entire family of languages-- such as the C family-- has a certain syntax, it is more costly to change.

Comment: Mathematicians actually are ambiguous, sometimes using = for assignment, and sometimes to indicate equality. But never to assign to the right, so you are essentially correct.

Comment: @FarmBoy: in mathematics, assignment and equality ARE the same thing, as there is no sequence in a formula as there is in computers. ( a equals b and at the same time b equals a )

Comment: @FarmBoy: right, mathematically the equalities are symetric, but assignments aren't equalities.  Still, when defining terms, (which are closer to assignments) the most used form is by far to put the newly defined term at the left.  That makes assignments much more readable for anybody that's comfortable with mathematical notations.

Comment: @FB except in some single assignment functional languages like e.g. Erlang. Assignment and Assuring equality are the same like in mathematics

Comment: @Petruza No, in mathematics assignment and equality are not the same thing. If I say 'Let x = 2y - 3' it is different from 'Thus x = 2y - 3'. I math, typically context differentiates them. Since The comment disputing me was so universally acclaimed, I'll mention that I do have a Ph.D. in mathematics, I'm pretty sure about this.

Comment: @FarmBoy, I too am a Mathematician, though I don't have a Ph.D. What was your emphasis?

Comment: @Petruza, I would like to add as proof that context tells us whether or not we are assigning or evaluating equality.
|x + y|^2 = < x + y, x + y > is a very famous equality. Also, if I was proving this I might even write--not really, I would use the Schwarz, but this is an example so whatever-- : Suppose that | x + y |^2 = <x+y, x+y> then .... This would be similar in language though maybe not completely in function to if(|x + y|^2 == <x+y, x+y>) { ... }. Anyways, my point is, context is indeed the determining factor.

Comment: @JohanthanHenson Topology. And thanks for providing a good example of the various meanings of '='.

Comment: @FarmBoy, My favorite before becoming a developer was Real Analysis and Complex Analysis. Also I am obsessed with Euler. However, now that I see its application in my field and have a way to enjoy it, my favorites are Abstract Algebra and Number Theory.

Comment: I don't know mathematics anywhere near a PhD, what I state is that as there is no sequentiality, there's no order of execution in mathematics both in an assignment or in an equality, unlike programming, in which both sides of an assignment can be different at some point in time, and they end up being equal at some other point in time. But in mathematics, in an assignment like `let a be...` as there is no time, both sides of the assignment are equal as well, so the assignment is in fact an equality, no wonder why both use the same sign: `=`

Comment: @Petruzza - but there *is* sequentiality. Mathematical documents are written from start to end, the same as any other document. If I assert `x = 1` in chapter one, but assert `x = 2` in chapter two, that isn't some terrible contradiction - each assertion applies only within a certain context. The difference in imperative programming is partly the removal of a barrier (we don't need a change of context), and partly about implementation and usefulness.

Answer (score 27):

`BASIC`, one of the earliest computer languages had the "proper" form of:

```
10 LET AREA = HEIGHT * WIDTH
```

which matches the mathematical mindset of specifying a variable, like "Let H be the height of the object".

`COBOL` was also similar with its `COMPUTE` statement. As with many ways of doing things, it may have simply been an arbitrary decision that was carried forward through many languages.

Comment: I suppose that this form is more natural when program lines are considered as "statements" as opposed to "operations." As in, `I declare that X must equal THIS`, instead of the more linear `Evaluate THIS and store it in X`

Comment: Wait, BASIC was an 'early' computer language?

Comment: @Alex Considering that it harkens from the 1960s, I'd say that's pretty early.

Comment: On the other hand, in COBOL you could write `MULTIPLY HEIGHT BY WIDTH GIVING AREA`, so the variable that gets the result is on the very right side of the statement.

Answer (score 25):

Actually, there is a programming language that assigns to the right side: [TI-BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-BASIC)! Not just that, but it also doesn't use '=' as the assignment operator, but rather uses an arrow known as the "STO" operator.

examples:

```
5→A
(A + 3)→B
(A - B)→C
```

In the above example, three variables are being declared and given values.  A would be 5, B would be 8, and C would be -3.  The first declaration/assignment can be read 'store 5 as A'.

As to why TI-BASIC uses such a system for assignment, I attribute it to being because it is a programming language for a calculator.  The "STO" operator on TI calculators was most often used in normal calculator operations *after* a number was calculated.  If it was a number the user wanted to remember, they would hit the "STO" button, and the caclulator would prompt them for a name (automatically engaging the alpha lock so that keystrokes produced letters instead of numbers):

```
Sin(7 + Cos(3))
                    -.26979276
Ans→{variable name}
                    -.26979276
```

and the user could name the variable whatever  they chose.  Having to turn on alpha lock, type the name, then press "STO", and hitting the "Ans" key would have been far too cumbersome for normal operations.  Since all calculator functions are available in TI-BASIC, no other assignment operators were added as "STO" performed the same task, albeit backwards when compared to most other languages.

(Anecdote:  TI-BASIC was one of the first languages I learned, so when I when I was first learning Java in college I felt as though assigning to the LEFT was unusual and 'backwards'!)

Comment: +1 I totally forgot that ! TI Basic was my very first language, too, but I don't remember this detail.

Comment: Actually the STO operator is closer to how the machine works, and how any language actually operates. The value is first calculated and then stored in memory.

Answer (score 16):

**Heuristic 1:** *When faced with more than one possible way of doing something while designing a language, pick the most common, most intuitive one, or else you will end up with Perl+.*

**Now,** how is it more natural (at least to an English speaker)?
Let's look at how we write/say things in English:

Steven is now 10 years old (as opposed to 10 years old Steven now is).
I weigh more than 190 pounds (as opposed to more than 190 pounds I weigh).

In code:

```
steven = 10
i > 190
```

The following also sounds more natural:

"If Mary is 18 yo, then she can have a candy".
"If I am younger than 21 yo, then I will ask my brother to by me tequila".

```
if (mary == 18) { ... }
if (i < 21) { ... }
```

than:

"If 18 yo Mary is ..."
"If 21 is greater than my age ... "

Now the code:

```
if (18 == mary) { ... }
if (21 > i) { ... }
```

Note that this is not natural to either programmers nor English speakers. The sentences sound like yoda-speak, and the code is nicknamed yoda-conditions. These might be helpful in C++, but I am sure most people would agree: if a compiler could do the heavy lifting and alleviate the need for yoda-conditions, life would be a bit easier.

Of course, one could get used to anything. For examples, number 81 is written as:

Eighty One (English)
Eighty and one (Spanish)
One and Eighty (German).

Finally, there are 4! = 24 valid ways of saying "green apple lies on table" in Russian - the order (almost) does not matter, except that 'on' must come together with 'table'. So, if you are a native Russian speaker (for example), then you might not care whether one writes `a = 10` or `10 = a` because both seem equally natural.

While linguistics is a fascinating subject, I never formally studied it and do not know that many languages. Hopefully I have provided enough counter-examples though.

Comment: My thoughts as well.  Even if one's first thought was to read `x = 1` as "x gets assigned to 1" (nonsense) you should quickly be able to figure out that it means "x is assigned 1".  The latter is more direct, not passive, and thus more natural.

Comment: Interesting observation, if the de facto standard language for IT wasn't english, this might have ended up being the other way around.

Comment: ... and in French, 81 is said as "four times twenty one" ... :)

Comment: @Martin, I believe Danish is very similar.

Comment: @Martin That's really weird, because four times twenty one is 84.

Comment: @Peter: you've got your parenthesis wrong, it's `(four times twenty) one`

Comment: In French it's actually *four twenty **and** one*, then *four twenty two* (sans *and*) up to *four twenty ten nine* (99).

Comment: Not so different from how we used to speak English: "four score and seven years ago."

Comment: if (900 == you)
  I.look != you.look

Comment: @Job: Reading your "If 18 yo Mary is ...", I was inevitably reminded of Yoda saying "When nine hundred years old you reach, look as good you will not, hmm?" in Return of the Jedi :-)

Comment: @Job: I was referring to Martin Sojka's comment, 'and in French, 81 is said as "four times twenty one"'. In Abraham Lincoln's day, it would not have been uncommon to refer to 81 as "four score one". I put the phrase "four score and seven years ago" because it the the beginning of a famous speech. I should have added [at]Martin Sojka to the beginning of my comment to be clearer.

Comment: @Daniel, my bad, I see now. Russians used to say 'two-five' to refer to 'ten' some 200 years ago.

Comment: I know this argument is long since dead, but this is horrendously contrived. I can say "If 18 years is Mary's age" and in English that reads just as clearly as "If Mary is 21 years old", the same is true about nearly every one of your examples.

Answer (score 11):

It started with FORTRAN in the 1950s. Where FORTRAN was an abbreviation of FORmula TRANslation -- the formulas in question being simple algebraic equations which by convention always assign to the left.

Its near contemporary COBOL on the other hand was meant to be English-like and assigned to the right (mostly!).

```
MOVE 1 TO COUNTER.
ADD +1 TO LINE-CNT.
MULTIPLY QTY BY PRICE GIVING ITEM-PRICE.
```

Comment: I think this is the best example here because it perfectly illustrates a context in a language where it's readable to a common English speaker but has right assignment. I'm saying that's important because of the large amount of people saying in English it would only read left to right for the assignment to make sense, which is absolutely not true.

Answer (score 5):

Well, as @diceguyd30 pointed out, there's both notations.

- `<Identifier> = <Value>` means "let *Identifier* be *Value*". Or to expand that: Define (or redefine) the variable *Identifier* to *Value*.
- `<Value> -> <Identifier>` means "store *Value* to *Identifier*". Or to expand that: Put *Value* into the location designated by *Identifier*.

Of course, generally speaking the *Identifier* may in fact be any L-value.

The first approach honors the abstract concept of variables, the second approach is more about actual storage.

Note that the first approach is also common in languages, that do not have assignments. Also note, that variable definition and assignment are relatively close `<Type> <Identifier> = <Value>` vs. `<Identifier> = <Value>`.

Answer (score 4):

It could be a remnant of early parsing algorithms. Remember that LR parsing was only invented in 1965, and it could well be that LL parsers had troubles (within the time and space limitations of the machines at the time) going the other way around. Consider:

```
identifier = function();
function();
```

The two are clearly disambiguated from the second token. On the other hand,

```
function() = identifier;
function();
```

Not fun. This gets worse when you start nesting assignment expressions.

```
function(prev_identifier = expression) = identifier;
function(prev_identifier = expression);
```

Of course, easier to disambiguate for machines also means easier to disambiguate for humans. Another easy example would be searching for the initialization of any given identifier.

```
identifier1 = expressionOfAnArbitraryLength;
identifier2 = expressionOfAReallyReallyReallyArbitraryLength;
identifier3 = expression;
identifier4 = AlongLineExpressionWithAFunctionCallWithAssignment(
    identifier = expr);
```

Easy, just look up the left side. Right side, on the other hand

```
expressionOfAnArbitraryLength = identifier1;
expressionOfAReallyReallyReallyArbitraryLength = identifier2;
expression = identifier3;
AlongLineExpressionWithAFunctionCallWithAssignment(expr = identifier
    ) = identifier4;
```

Especially when you can't `grep` punch cards, it's much harder to find the identifier you want.

Comment: Precisely the point that I had thought of, yes.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been mentioned, pretty well all the early computer languages worked that way.  E.g. FORTRAN, which came along many years before BASIC.

It actually makes a great deal of sense to have the assigned variable on the left of the assignment expression.  In some languages, you might have several different overloaded routines with the SAME NAME, returning different types of result.  By letting the compiler see the type of the assigned variable first, it knows which overloaded routine to call, or what implicit cast to generate when converting from (e.g.) an integer to a float.  That's a bit of a simplistic explanation, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I understand your explanation, but could not the compiler just look ahead until the end of the statement?

Comment: That might make the lexer simpler in today's languages, but how many programming languages even supported named methods, let alone method overloads, when this kind of syntax was new?

Comment: Hi @voithos.  Yes - the compiler could look ahead, but that would probably have been an unacceptable level of complexity in the early days of compiler writing - which was often hand-coded assembler!  I think that putting the assigned variable on the left is a pragmatic choice: it's easier for both man and machine to parse.

Comment: I think it would be trivial for an assignment to assign to the right. When a expression like 3+4==6+7, both sides are evaluated before the operator is, because the language is defined recursively. The language element 'variable = expression', could easily be changed to 'expression = variable'. Whether or not that causes ambiguous situations depends on the rest of the language.

Comment: @Kratz - that's certainly true for compilers now, but there may have been a minor issue for very old interpreted languages that worked with tokenized source. OTOH, that might have favored variable-on-the-right rather than variable-on-the-left.

Answer (score 2):

[Asssembly languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) have the destination as part of the left-hand opcode. Higher level languages tended to follow the conventions of the predecessor languages.

When you see `=` (or `:=` for Pascalish dialects), you could pronounce those as `is assigned the value`, then the left-to-right nature will make sense (because we also read left-to-right in most languages). Since programming languages were predominantly developed by folks who read left-to-right, the conventions stuck.

It is a type of [path dependence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_dependence). I suppose if computer programming was invented by people who spoke Hebrew or Arabic (or some other right-to-left language), then I suspect we'd be putting the destination on the right.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect that the text in the editors would be right-aligned as well...

Comment: You can't generalise like that about assembly languages. They vary as to where the destination operand is.

Comment: @quickly_now: right; in fact, most of the primitive machine languages (not even assemblers by today's standards) didn't even have destination, as there was usually just one or two general-purpose accumulators.  most operations implied the accumulator as destination, except for 'store' opcodes, which specified only the memory address and not the source (which was the accumulator).  I really don't think it was any influence on assignment syntax for ALGOL-like languages.

Comment: @Tangurena - *Some* assembler languages have the destimation on the left. *Not* of the opcode (that's the assembled object code), but the left of the arguments list for the instruction mnemonic. However, others have the destination on the right. In 68000 assembler, you'd write `mov.b #255, d0`, for instance, where `d0` is the register to assign to. Older assemblers only have a single argument per instruction. In the 6502 `LDA #255` (Load Accumulator), you could argue that the `A` is on the left, but it's also on the left in `STA wherever` (Store Accumulator).

Comment: And even the Intel 4004 (the 4-bit ultimate ancestor of the 8086 family, with the 8008 and 8080 in between) was developed *after* assignment in high level languages. If you're assuming that the 8086 series is representative of what assemblers did in the 50s and earlier, I very much doubt that's true.

Comment: GAS assembly syntax is the exception where destination is the last parameter

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, most statements in COBOL read from left to right, so the two operands were named first, and the destination last, like: `multiply salary by rate giving tax`.

I won't however, suggest that your student might prefer COBOL, for fear that I'd be (quite rightly) flagged for making such a low, uncouth, tasteless comment! :-)

Answer (score 2):

> she said that left-to-right seemed more natural to her, since that's how most of us read natural languages.

I think this is a mistake. On the one hand, you can say "assign 10 to x" or "move 10 to x". On the other hand, you can say "set x to 10" or "x becomes 10".

In other words, depending on your choice of verb, the assigned-to variable may or may not be the subject, and may or may not be on the left. So "what is natural" just depends entirely on your habitual choice of wording to represent assignment.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudocode the assignment operator is very commonly written on the right. For example

```
2*sqrt(x)/(3+y) -> z
```

In Casio calculators, even non-programmable variants, the assignment variable is also displayed on the right

```
A+2B → C
```

In Forth the variable is on the right, too

```
expression variable !
```

In x86, Intel syntax has the destination on the left, but GAS syntax reverses the order, making some confusion to many people, especially on instructions regarding parameters' order like subtraction or comparisons. These instructions are the same in 2 different dialects

```
mov rax, rbx    ; Intel syntax
movq %rbx, %rax ; GAS syntax
```

They both move the value in rbx to rax. No other assembly languages I know write the destination on the right like GAS.

> Some platforms put the expression on the left and the variable on the right:
>
> ```
> MOVE expression TO variable      COBOL
> expression → variable            TI-BASIC, Casio BASIC
> expression -> variable           BETA, R
> put expression into variable     LiveCode
> ```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Notation

Most languages assign the value to the left, one of the reasons being easy to align the operators, easier to read and recognize the variable, as the assignment operators and variables' positions will not vary wildly in the lines, and it's easier to read as "let variable be some value".

However some people prefer to say "move value x to y" and write the variable on the right.

Answer (score -2):

I think it follows a logical way of thinking.
There has to be a box (variable) first, then you put an object (value) inside it.
You don't put the object in the air and then put a box around it.

Comment: yes you do.  in most languages the right side is evaluated before the left one.

Comment: Its a "Driving on the Right side of the road" type of thing. It seems logical but only because its the way you have always done it. All superior countries drive on the Left.

Comment: @JamesAnderson superior countries? :o

Comment: You're right, it's only logical for a left to right writing system as the roman alphabet, which I guess is used by almost every programming language, if not all.